# Running shiny application on server

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I launched my shiny application on server, you can have from here : https://fahim.shinyapps.io/test3/

But it's very slow, however all of my files that i have used are less than 50 KB.
Can anyone help me how to solve this problem please.

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Comment: What do you mean by slow? Which part of the app is slow? Or do you mean loading the app itself?

Comment: Btw just clicking around randomly, I got this error: `Error evaluating expression: input.box == TRUE`. Conditional panel expressions have to be in JavaScript, which uses `true` instead of the all-caps `TRUE` in R.

Comment: The problem for my curent app is fixed now, just for your information i was loading csv files with read.csv and  when i use fread command it's running fast. Thank you all.